# getQueryString returns empty string when queryParameter has no value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have URL like http://example.com/foo/?locale=en_US&xyz, when i do a getQueryString() on the URL i get back an empty String

I am doing "request.getQueryString()" on the URL

Comment: Missing complete code

Comment: Maybe you are doing a POST (like in a form) or you URL encoded the entire URL so `?` is actually `%3F` (sometimes shown URL decoded in some browsers).

Answer (score 1):

`getQuery()` works for me:

```
     String str = "http://example.com/foo/?locale=en_US&xyz";
     URL url = new URL(str);
     System.out.println(url.getQuery());
```

Output: `locale=en_US&xyz`

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but this did not work for me.

Comment: Very odd... What output did you get? Which Java version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

[Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) says

> Returns: a String containing the query string or null if the URL
>   contains no query string. The value is not decoded by the container.

The value is not decoded by the container.

```
String queryString = URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");
```

This will make getQueryString() work.

Recommend to get params using [getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)